# Google Finance Sheets: Dividends and Stock Splits

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am building a Google Finance Spread Sheet for my portfolio and curious about a few things.

Generally, I am trying to calculate the monthly returns for each month and essentially outputted the beginning and ending market values for each stock and summed them together.

First, there are stock splits that can occur over time. While Google Finance adjusts the share price for these splits, the number of shares that I own has been manually entered in a set of cells in the above described computation. How do I adjust this for select time periods? More generally, is there a seamless way to calculate the market value as I have described accounting for the fact that sometimes my assets might change? I realize you can do this on a month to month basis *manually*, adjusting the assets, but wondering if this is the only way?

Second, how do I incorporate dividend data into my spreadsheet?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Would you please share a brief description of you search/research efforts. Reference [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, we work on the basis of one post/one question. So, you should ask a new question for information about dividends.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.